# Creating lists with loops and writing it to a csv. arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r

I have a csv with multiple columns, and 6 rows of values for each id , and 20 ids in total (120 rows)
I have to extract the rows where the median of any of the row is above a threshold.

I attempted this by splitting the csv into a list on ID
then a nested loop iteration through each column and saving the median to another list and then reconstructing a list

```
  j=2 for (each in lst) {   i=1   column =22   while(column<30){
    mlist[[i]]<-median(each[[column]])
    column=column+1
    i=i+1   }   z=22   for (cols in mlist) {
    if (cols>10^-6) {
        DF[[j]][[2]]<-each$SubjectID[[2]]
        DF[[j]][[z]]<-cols

        }else{
          DF[[j]][[2]]<-each$SubjectID[[2]]
          DF[[j]][[z]]<-0}
    z=z+1   } j=j+1 }
```

The idea was to have the median saved into a list and then populate the median into its respective column in a new list. My code is producing a list where the rows do not have equal elements and hence cannot be written into a csv

Comment: I'm guessing that would be the median of the group being the threshold but it is rather clear what the rule for choosing really is. You should post some sample data with code and specify a threshold.

Comment: Perhaps you could do this: 1) read the CSV file into a data frame with `read.csv`; 2) add a median column by `df$median <- apply(df, 1, median)`; and 3) select the rows for output as follows: `output <- df[df$median>threshold,]`

Comment: That would calculate the median of the entire data set. I need the median of each subject id. and each column.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/. In general on SO, providing sample data and expected output increases likelihood that you'll get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

library `dplyr` makes grouping and summarizing very simple. (In future please provide sample data)

```
df <- read.csv(text="
id,value
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
")
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id ) %>%
  summarize(median_value = median(value))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
#         id median_value
#      <int>        <int>
#    1     1            2
#    2     2            5
```